# Why do I get "... is not a function at HTMLButtonElement" error?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a function called "reset" in an event listener but I get the error "reset" is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.

```
for(var i = 0; i < gameMode.length; i++){
    gameMode[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < gameMode.length; i++){
            gameMode[i].classList.remove("selected");/*this line initially removes the class "selected" from all elements*/
            this.classList.add("selected");/*it then adds it only to the element that was clicked*/
        }

        this.textContent === "Easy" ? numSquares = 3: numSquares = 6;
        reset();
        
    })
}

function reset(){
    reset.innerHTML = "New Colors";
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    h1.style.backgroundColor = "steelblue";
    colors = randomColorArr(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    
    //console.log("value of picedColor inside reset event listener: "+pickedColor);
    colorDisplay.innerHTML = pickedColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `reset.innerHTML = "New Colors";` that looks suspicious (and it does absolutely nothing) ... are you re-declaring `reset` somewhere? if this is the whole code, then, other than setting a property of the function reset to `new colors` (which won't actually do much) it should not give that error

Comment: come on!! There must be more code than this, and in that code you must be setting `reset` to be some element of your HTML - which is why a) it's no longer a function and b) you attempt to modify its innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I had set "reset" earlier in my js code to another variable. Renaming the earlier variable from " reset" to something else solved the issue.

Rookie mistake.